# Use VBA DIctionary To Sum Rows With Same ID Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I am attempting (currently via a dictionary) to address the example data below:

```
Sales Amount     Product       ID        Count
    100           apple      123ABC       1
    50            apple      456DEF       2
    50            apple      456DEF       2
    200           orange     456DEF       2
    200           orange     456DEF       2
    900           tomato     789GHI       1
    75            orange     999PPP       2
    25            apple      999PPP       2
    25            apple      999PPP       2
```

What I need to do is: for any lines that has a `count` of >1, sum the sales amount for all rows which share an ID but have different products.  I then want to write the sum values over the existing values in the `Sales Amount` Column.  The end results would look like this:

```
  Sales Amount   Product       ID        Count
    100           apple      123ABC       1
    250           apple      456DEF       2
    250           apple      456DEF       2
    250           orange     456DEF       2
    250           orange     456DEF       2
    900           tomato     789GHI       1
    100           orange     999PPP       2
    100           apple      999PPP       2
    100           apple      999PPP       2
```

The tricky part is that I only want to use the `Sales Amount` once per each `product`.  So for example ID 456DEF, I only want to add 50 for apple and 200 for orange.  My current code (see below) is summing all values in `Sales Amount` column for each ID.  So given that same example ID 456DEF, my code outputs a `Sales Amount` of 500 on each row for the ID (200+200+50+50).

Current Code:

```
Sub WontWorkYet

Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowForDict As Long, LastRowResult As Long, shtSource As      Worksheet, shtResult As Worksheet
Dim p As Long


Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws

    LastRowForDict = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For p = 1 To LastRowForDict

    If ws.Cells(p, 4) > 1 Then               'checks if count column for unique products is >1

    x = .Range("C1:C" & LastRowForDict).Value
    x2 = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowForDict).Value


        'If key exists already ADD new value (SUM them)


If Not dict.exists(x(p, 1)) Then
    dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = x2(p, 1)
Else
   dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(p, 1))) + CDbl(x2(p, 1))
End If

End If
Next p


End With


'map the values
  With ws
    LastRowResult = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("C2:C" & LastRowResult).Value    'looks up to this range
  y2 = .Range("A2:A" & LastRowForDict).Value   'Sizes the output array without a Re-Dim which allows existing values to not be wiped out in column CL


    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
       Else


        End If
    Next i
    .Range("A2:A" & LastRowResult).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
End With


End Sub
```

My idea was to potentially concatenate the `ID` with the `Product` and then remove this line which sums the already existing keys: `dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(p, 1))) + CDbl(x2(p, 1))`.  This would store the values correctly (I believe) in the dictionary, but then I got stuck trying to find a way to finish off the process by summing the stored amounts for each ID and write them to the sheet properly.

I know an array formula could be used to solve this, but the data set I am using is large and the array formula would be too slow.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you could turn this worksheet into a table, I think a query would handle this quite nicely.

Comment: @Karlomanio Unfortunately, this sheet is used frequently by other parts of this macro, and then manually by myself and other users.  I'd rather not change the format and cause issues with other parts of the code or anyone else's manual process.  If I could maybe change it to a table, query, then convert back to range without disturbing any data on sheet, that might be an option, but does not sound ideal.

Comment: If you have duplicate products meeting criteria but with different sales amounts, how do you choose which one to add?

Comment: How many distinct `ID`s do you have on your real data set? You may try to process data with SQL, that is quite fast, but all changes made to the workbook should be saved prior to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, try this formula. Is it still too slow?

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$10/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,$C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10),--($C$2:$C$10=C2))
```

**Secondly**, this can be a simple operation with help from *remove duplicates*. Try this:

1. Paste all of your data into sheet2, select the whole range and click *Data>Remove Duplicates>OK*

Your data in sheet2 now looks like this:

```
Sales Amount    Product ID  Count
100    apple    123ABC      1
50     apple    456DEF      2
200    orange   456DEF      2
900    tomato   789GHI      1
75     orange   999PPP      2
25     apple    999PPP      2
```

2. Now just go back to your first table and in `A2` place the following formula and drag down:

   =SUMIF(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!C2,Sheet2!A:A)

---

*Et voila*, as required. All from a simple and quick `SUMIF` formula.

```
Sales Amount    Product ID  Count
100     apple   123ABC      1
250     apple   456DEF      2
250     apple   456DEF      2
250     orange  456DEF      2
250     orange  456DEF      2
900     tomato  789GHI      1
100     orange  999PPP      2
100     apple   999PPP      2
100     apple   999PPP      2
```

Such a simple process can easily be automated using VBA too.

Comment: I believe this logic will work!  I'm going to automate via macro and test for performance - sometimes even applying a `SUMIF` formula on sheet can really make things lag as this sheet often contains upwards of 750K rows.